# Convenience vs Decoupling/Composition

Tags: composition, coupling, python-3.x, abstract-factory

Let's say I have a small CD burning library written in Python, with a CD class and a Burner interface + implementation classes:

```
# Module cd.py
class CD:
  def __init__(self):
    self.folders = []
    self.files = []

# Module burners/burners.py
BURNERS = []

# Module burners/cdburnerxp.py
class CDBurnerXP(CDBurner):
  def burn_cd(self, cd):
    # burn baby burn
BURNERS.append(CDBurnerXP)
```

If I would like to add a convenient method to class `CD`:

```
def burn(self):
    return BURNERS[0].burn_cd(self)
```

will it cause any problems in the future? Is it considered more coupled than instantiating the burner outside by ourselves?

---

Also, if I wish to add a factory to recreate a `CD` from a physical drive:

```
# Module factories/drive.py
from cd import CD
DriveBasedCDFactory(CDFactory):
    def create_cd(self):
        # stuff
        return CD()
```

Will adding a

```
@classmethod
def from_drive(cls):
  return DriveBasedCDFactory().create_cd()
```

to `CD` also cause more coupling? How can I resolve the implicit circular import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convenience method creates a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) with `CD` and `Burner` (which you've seen through the circular import). This is always a design smell, and instead of trying to fix the immediate symptom, you should take a step back and reflect on the design. I think you already have a good design without the `burn` method on `CD`. It's very clear that you use an instance of `Burner` to burn a `CD`. It allows me as the user to choose which implementation of `Burner` I want to use, and I can even create my own implementation if yours are lacking. The convenience method on the other hand is extremely inflexible. You can't choose which burner to user--it's tightly-coupled to `BURNERS[0]`. It may just confuse users. Finally it's difficult to unit test `CD.burn` because the tight-coupling and globals. The same limitations apply to `CD.from_drive`.

I suggest you have only have one way to accomplish a task. Having a convenience method in CD makes it unclear to the user whether they should use that method or use the `Burner` instance directly. If you add it now, you'll have to keep supporting it (or break clients), and it will set a poor precedent for other contributors for adding these kinds of methods.

As an advocate of [anaemic data models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) I recommend not adding behavior to your `CD` class and keeping it as pure data--files and folders.

Comment: How can I make it more comfortable though? Requiring the user to import many modules is rather dull and repetitive no?

Comment: I think your design is pretty straightforward to understand. I think with proper documentation it will be easy for the user to understand how to burn a CD.